# How to assign class="active" to menu in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I want that when i click on any link the link clicked gets the class="active" ,

```
<div style="width: 180px;">     
    <ul class="nav nav-list well">
      <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Clientes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Clientes Potenciales</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Suplidores</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Partners</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Contactos</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
        <li class="{if {$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI} == 'clientes'}active{/if}"><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Clientes</a></li>
        <li class="{if {$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI} == 'clientes2'}active{/if}"><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Clientes2</a></li>
```

But no luck, its not working, can anyone help me out ? im trying to do this with Smarty

Comment: shouldn't the links in the html be `href="/clientes"` and `href="/clientes2"`?

Comment: also try using `$smarty.server.REDIRECT_URL` instead

Comment: i tried:

    <li class="{if $smarty.server.PHP_SELF  == '#'}active{/if}"><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Clientes</a></li>
    <li class="{if $smarty.server.PHP_SELF  == '#'}active{/if}"><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Clientes2</a></li>

When i click any of the 2 link i just want it to be class="active", but its not doing anything

i tried with PHP_SELF and nothing happens!

Comment: this is a job for javascript if you're not actually changing a page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use javascript:

```
<div style="width: 180px;">     
    <ul class="nav nav-list well">
      <li id="li_0" class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Clientes</a></li>
      <li id="li_1"><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Clientes Potenciales</a></li>
      <li id="li_2"><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Suplidores</a></li>
      <li id="li_3"><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Partners</a></li>
      <li id="li_4"><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Contactos</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    var listItems=4;

    for (var i=0;i<listItems;i++) {
        document.getElementById("li_"+i).onclick=function() {
            resetClasses();
            this.className="active";
        }
    }

    function resetClasses() {
        for (var i=0;i<listItems;i++) {
            document.getElementById("li_"+i).className="";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Worked great!! you are my savior! Thanks!

Comment: Dave, I just noticed that when i add an href for example: <a href="clientes.php?view=clientes">  when it enters the link the class active get lost, can it be fixed with javascript?

Comment: see if `$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI` is equal to `clientes`, if it is, then use the code you had before

Comment: ok ill look to another solution, but for # worked great thanks Chen